# Vue: Check if the image was loaded and show a skeleton loader if not

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs3, loader

I need to check if the image was loaded by the browser and if all data was fetched, then display a content, if not, show `<ItemCardSkeleton />` component instead. So if one image is loaded faster than the others, I would want to show the content, and rest would have a skeleton until they are fully loaded one by one.

Here I pass the `isLoaded` and listen to a custom event `update:isLoaded` using `v-model`. To check if the image was loaded I use `@load` event and assign `$emit('update:isLoaded', true)` to it. And then I use `v-if` in parent component `<template v-if="storeRecipes.pending || isLoaded === false">` to check if data or image was loaded.

Problem:
If I reload the page I can see the skeleton loader, but it disappears on every card before the images were loaded. Which means it's only shown when the data is pending, but not when the images are loading. Any ideas?

Parent component ItemSwiper.vue:

```
<template>
    <Swiper
        class="swiper"
        :breakpoints="swiperOptions.breakpoints"
        :pagination="{
            clickable: true,
        }"
        :loop="true"
        :modules="swiperOptions.modules">
        <template v-if="storeRecipes.pending || isLoaded === false">
            <SwiperSlide class="swiper__slide" v-for="item in 3" :key="item">
                <ItemCardSkeleton />
            </SwiperSlide>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
            <template v-for="recipe in storeRecipes.data" :key="recipe.id">
                <SwiperSlide class="swiper__slide">
                    <ItemCard :data="recipe" v-model:isLoaded="isLoaded" />
                </SwiperSlide>
                <div class="swiper-custom-pagination"></div>
            </template>
        </template>
    </Swiper>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import { Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';
import 'swiper/css/free-mode';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css';
import { useStoreRecipes } from '@/stores/recipes/storeRecipes.js';

import ItemCard from '@/components/ItemCard.vue';
import ItemCardSkeleton from '@/components/SkeletonLoaders/ItemCardSkeleton.vue';

const storeRecipes = useStoreRecipes();
const isLoaded = ref();
  
onMounted(() => {
    storeRecipes.loadRecipes();
});
</script>
```

Child component ItemCard.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__item">
            <img
                class="card__image"
                @load="$emit('update:isLoaded', true)"
                :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
                :alt="data.alt"/>
            <div class="card__content">
                <h2 class="card__title">{{ data.title }}</h2>
                <p class="card__text">{{ data.text }}</p>
                <router-link class="card__link" :to="{ name: 'Home' }"
                    >View more</router-link
                >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['data', 'isLoaded']);
const emit = defineEmits(['update:isLoaded']);

const getSrc = ext => {
    return new URL(
        `../assets/images/recipe/${props.data.image}${ext}`,
        import.meta.url
    ).href;
};
</script>
```

Global store:

```
export const useStoreRecipes = defineStore('storeRecipes', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            data: [],
            pending: false,
        };
    },
    actions: {
        async loadRecipes() {
            try {
                this.pending = true;
                const res = await fetch('/api/recipe');
                if (res.ok) {
                    const data = await res.json();
                    this.data = data;
                } else {
                    console.error('Error: ', res.status, res.statusText);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } finally {
                this.pending = false;
            }
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

call `ref()` without any initial param means `undefined`.

so `isLoaded === false` comparison equals `undefined === false` and returns `false` not `true`.

you should do: `const isLoaded = ref(false)`

Extra: this to help clarify what you expect in the comment

```
// your ItemCard.vue
<script setup>
    // pending now is a prop and you pass `storeRecipes.pending` here
    const props = defineProps(['data', 'isLoaded', 'pending']);
    const isLoaded = ref(false)
</script>

<template>
    <img v-if="pending || isLoaded" .... />
    <div v-else>This div is just example of what you had inside ItemCardSkeleton</div>
</template>
```

Note that: the code is just an example, you replace them with your origin template

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't solve the issue. Someone told me that in order to achieve what I need, I would need to keep track of loading state per recipe instead
and that my skeleton needs to be in the loop.

Comment: the simplest way is to move `isLoaded` into your `ItemCard`. Next move the implement of `ItemCardSkeleton` into `ItemCard` too. Now do `if-else` inside your `ItemCard`. If is loaded => use origin `ItemCard` implementation, else (not loaded) use implementation of `ItemCardSkeleton`

Comment: ItemCard:
`code
     <template v-if="isLoaded">
    <img
 class="card__image"
 @load="$emit('update:isLoaded', true)"
 :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
:alt="data.alt"/>
     </div>
     </template>
     <template v-else>
<ItemCardSkeleton />
     </template>
`

ItemSwiper:
`code
storeRecipes.pending || !isLoaded then show <ItemCard :data="null" v-model:isLoaded="isLoaded" />, v-else if recipe in storeRecipes.data" :key="recipe.id" show <ItemCard :data="recipe" v-model:isLoaded="isLoaded" />:
`
But, I feel it's not correct. (sorry I can't paste the code here, limited by characters)

Comment: you feel it's not correct and it's true coz that is not what I mean :P check the update.

Comment: cards disappeared.
ItemCard:
`code
const props = defineProps(['data', 'isLoaded', 'pending']); 
const emit = defineEmits(['update:isLoaded']); 
`
template:
`code
<template v-if="pending || isLoaded">` 
then show the img+content, and else `code <template v-else>` show `code <ItemCardSkeleton />`.
ItemSwiper:
`code const isLoaded = ref(false);`
template:
`code
<template v-for="recipe in storeRecipes.data" :key="recipe.id">
<SwiperSlide class="swiper__slide">
<ItemCard
:data="recipe"
:pending="storeRecipes.pending"
 v-model:isLoaded="isLoaded" />
</SwiperSlide>
</template>
`

Comment: It seems like you are lacking the basic of how things work. We provided `isLoaded` for each `ItemCard`. So there is no `v-model` at each `ItemCard` anymore. Moreover, `v-if` should be put at child tag, not directly at `<template>` tag. Each component should have 1 root `<template>` tag only. I suggest you look back the official document for conditional rendering: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if . At the moment, no matter what I wrote, it will not be useful for you. Just read the doc then you will understand what my example means.

Comment: A use of <template> inside the main <template> of .vue files means that we want to use an invisible wrapper of v-if, v-else or v-for directives for a group of elements. How do I suppose to display  <ItemCardSkeleton /> if I not only have the <img> but the <div class="card__content"> as well?

Comment: @Michael, I don't say you can't have nested `<template>` tag. But nested `<template>` tag has many roles within `Vue.js`. I also don't say you can't put `v-if` at `<template>` tag. I meant your code is not matched to my example. I believe I am useless now. You need an experience developer next to you to help you with this.